# Will importing a repository from bitbucket to github (for opensource projects) bring the activities to GitGub?

Tags: github, bitbucket

So a company I work for is going to realease on of their softwares as opensource and I'd very much like to have the contributions show up on my github profile, is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the email address you used for your Bitbucket is the same as the email on GitHub, your contribution would be shown on your GitHub profile.